# how i get my 2nd id in the join table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT package.pkg_name, pkg.cat_id,pkg.id
FROM pkg
INNER JOIN package ON pkg.id=package.id
join categories ON pkg.cat_id=1=categories.cat_id=1
```

1st id is show in join table but 2nd id does not show in the join table

Comment: It is valid SQL, it just doesn't do what you expect it to do. It's as if you did `((pkg.cat_id=1)=categories.cat_id)=1`.

Comment: @BillKarwin, are you really sure it's valid? I can't figure out how, reading the SQL-2016 specification.

Comment: @jarlh: yes Bill Karwin is right, it would compile in MySQL, although it's not valid ANSI SQL.But that's surely not what the OP wants, though.

Comment: It's valid in MySQL because the result of a boolean comparison is actually an integer 1 or 0, which can then be compared to another integer (or another boolean). MySQL is nonstandard in this way. It's not valid per the ANSI SQL spec, because booleans are not integers in the standard. This probably won't work in other implementations of SQL either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to select records where `categories id` equals to 1. This should work:

```
SELECT package.pkg_name, pkg.cat_id, pkg.id
FROM pkg
INNER JOIN package ON pkg.id = package.id
JOIN categories ON pkg.cat_id = categories.cat_id
WHERE categories.cat_id = 1;
```

This joins all 3 tables together + shows you the record where `categories.cat_id = 1`